# $\big(k[X,Y]/(H)\big)_{(X,Y)}\cong k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra

> I'm trying to understand why $\big(k[X,Y]/(H)\big)_{(X,Y)}\cong k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(H)$, where $k$ is a field and $H$ is an irreducible polynomial.

I need this result in a theorem I'm proving, I searched on Atiyah and Macdonald's commutative algebra book without success. I'm almost sure I've already seen a theorem in some commutative algebra book which this result is an easy corollary.

Thanks

Comment: Actually you also have to localize the ideal $(H)$ at $(X,Y)$ before you can take the quotient on the right. Now ask yourself when that localization is not zero. There is a general proposition that establishes the relation between the prime ideals of a ring and prime ideals of a localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give it away: You are looking for Corollary 3.4 in Atiyah/MacDonald.

Comment: Do you mean corollary 3.4 part (iii)? what I get is $\big(k[X,Y]/(H)\big)_{(X,Y)}\cong k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(H)_{(X,Y)}$, it's not what I want. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RafaelChaves But those two are the same. The ideal you get by sending $H$ to the localization and letting it generate an ideal there is exactly the same as what you get by localizing the ideal.

Comment: @Arthur I didn't follow you. Could you write this in mathematical symbols? Thank you.

Comment: @RafaelChavez I assume, when you write $k[X, Y]_{(X, Y)}/(H)$, you mean that $(H)$ is the ideal of $k[X, Y]_{(X, Y)}$ generated by the polynomial $H$ seen as an element of $k[X, Y]_{(X, Y)}$. What is usually done, however, is to look at the ideal $(H)_{(X, Y)}$, which A-M calls $(H)^{\mathfrak{c}}$. It is made by taking the ideal $(H)\subseteq k[X, Y]$, and sending all the elements of it to the localization, and see what ideal they generate there. These two approaches gives you the same ideal, which means that $k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(H)_{(X,Y)}$ and $k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(H)$ are the same thing.

Comment: This is what I meant in the comment to the original question. You first have to understand how (prime) ideals in the localization correspond to prime ideals in the orginal ring. Basically: When does an element become zero in the localization? This is explained beautifully (I think) in Chapter 2 of Eisenbud's book on Commutative Algebra.

Comment: @Arthur of course, thank you!